# Replace c# Serialize to python

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, sockets

I have a very specific problem and I hope that I get some direction for a solution, first I am not a guy of C# And I have no prior knowledge of this language.
My mission is to replace some code (C#) and write this in python.
the code makes serialization to some data and sends this struct in UDP. On the other side the client takes the data and makes deserialize still in c# this side I not going to replace and I can't replace.
In python, I use pickle to make serialization and I send tuple, unfortunately, it's not working I see a difference in Wireshark when I send from C# code the length of the message equal to   1264 bytes and from python 175 bytes.
Would appreciate help..

Example C# serialize (I want replace this part):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace VMSProxyClient
{
[Serializable]
public class TelemetryUdpPacket //OCU to VMS and VMS to OCU
{
    public bool IsToVMS { get; set; }
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public bool IsDay { get; set; }
    public bool IsDprOk { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public int  Quality { get; set; }
    public bool IsSendTo { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double AboveSeaLevel { get; set; }

    public double Yaw   { get; set; }
    public double Pitch { get; set; }
    public double Roll  { get; set; }

    public double GimbalPitch   { get; set; }
    public double GimbalRoll    { get; set; }

    public double HorizontalFov { get; set; }
    public double VerticalFov   { get; set; }

    public PacketPoint3D FootprintCenter { get; set; }
    public PacketPoint3D FootprintTopLeft { get; set; }
    public PacketPoint3D FootprintTopRight { get; set; }
    public PacketPoint3D FootprintBottomRight { get; set; }
    public PacketPoint3D FootprintBottomLeft { get; set; }
    public List<string> MapList { get; set; }

    public static TelemetryUdpPacket Deserialize(byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var result = (TelemetryUdpPacket)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize(TelemetryUdpPacket packet)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, packet);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

}

my python code :

```
import websocket
import json
import pickle
import ipaddress
from typing import NamedTuple
import socket


class TelemetryUdpPacket(NamedTuple):
   IsToVMS: bool
   Timestamp: float
   IsDay: bool
   IsDprOk: bool
   IsLocked: bool
   Quality: int
   IsSendTo: bool
   Longitude: float
   Latitude: float
   AboveSeaLevel: float
   Yaw: float
   Pitch: float
   Roll: float
   GimbalPitch: float
   GimbalRoll: float
   HorizontalFov: float
   VerticalFov: float
   FootprintCenter: list
   FootprintTopLeft: list
   FootprintTopRight: list
   FootprintBottomRight: list
   FootprintBottomLeft: list
   MapList: str


class ProxyServer:
   def __init__(self, PORT=8090, IP='11.11.11.4'):
           self.PORT = PORT
           self.IP = ipaddress.ip_address(IP)
           print(f"STARTING WBSOCKET = ws://{self.IP}:{self.PORT}/Protrack- 
           Locator/Data/LocationResults")
           self.opened_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # Start 
           UDP to send buffer to ProxyClient
           self.opened_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # 
           Addition command to close socket port immediately
           self.opened_socket.bind(("11.11.11.6", 40005)) # Initalize my local: IP, PORT
           wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(f"ws://{self.IP}:{self.PORT}/Protrack- 
           Locator/Data/LocationResults",
                                   on_message=self.on_message)
             wsapp.run_forever()

def SendUDP(self, buffer, IP='11.11.11.5', PORT=40006):
    try:
        self.opened_socket.sendto(buffer, (IP, PORT))
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in SendUDP Function: {e}")
        return -1


def on_message(self, wsapp, message):
    # first parsing data from locator
    message = json.loads(message.decode('utf-8'))
    # Sort data before sending to Proxy client
    packet = TelemetryUdpPacket(False, message['Time']['MsgEpochTimestamp'], bool(message['CameraModel']['Type']),
                                True,
                                True, message['State']['LockSate'], True, message['SelfPosition']['Lon'],
                                message['SelfPosition']['Lat'],
                                message['SelfPosition']['Alt'], message['CameraModel']['Heading'],
                                message['CameraModel']['Pitch'],
                                message['CameraModel']['Roll'], 0, 0, message['CameraModel']['HorzFov'],
                                message['CameraModel']['VertFov'],
                                [message['MapFootprint']['Center']['Lon'], message['MapFootprint']['Center']['Lat'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['Center']['Alt']],
                                [message['MapFootprint']['TopLeft']['Lon'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['TopLeft']['Lat'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['TopLeft']['Alt']],
                                [message['MapFootprint']['TopRight']['Lon'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['TopRight']['Lat'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['TopRight']['Alt']],
                                [message['MapFootprint']['BottomRight']['Lon'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['BottomRight']['Lat'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['BottomRight']['Alt']],
                                [message['MapFootprint']['BottomLeft']['Lon'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['BottomLeft']['Lat'],
                                 message['MapFootprint']['BottomLeft']['Alt']],
                                "API_is_Working!")
    # Now we make Serializable in python
    buff = pickle.dumps(packet)
    self.UDPCheck = self.SendUDP(buff)
 


x = ProxyServer()
```

Comment: You are out of luck: It uses the binary formatter, which is **very** specific to the runtime in use. It is _very_ expensive to recreate the exact binary format from python (or any other language).

Comment: ^^ That being said, if you are still in need to switch to python for the sender side _and you are allowed to change the receiver side_, you may find some serialization format, that both languages have implementations / libs for and use that instead.

Comment: By the way: Another incentive to move away from BinaryFormatter - _" Warning
BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure. For more information, see the BinaryFormatter security guide."_ [BinaryFormatter class - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: In that context, [this article](https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2019/09/29/net-serialization-benchmark-2019-roundup/) may be of interest for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand that I don't have many options I need to switch to python for the sender side and change the code on the receiver side. You have some specific formats that you recommend That will require a minimum change in C # code.

Comment: I have not looked into serialization formats in a while, so anything I would recommend could be outdated. It also depends on your requirements and optimization goals. So you are probably better off doing your own research than depend on my recommendation.